# Mocked DbSet not returning an object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, generics, moq

I am trying to test an update function by mocking the data using Moq. I am using Entity Framework 6.

I can print out a count of the `DbSet` and it is the expected amount. However, when it tries to select an object, it throws an exception, `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Here is my test class which sets up the mocked `DbSets` and `DbContext`

```
[TestFixture]
public class ProductControllerTest
{
    private ProductController controller;
    private IProductRepository productRepo;
    private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    private IBrandRepository brandRepo;
    private ICategoryRepository categoryRepo;
    private ISegmentRepository segmentRepo;
    private ITypeRepository typeRepo;
    private IEnumerable<Product> productList;

    [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        IEnumerable<Brand> brandList = new List<Brand>{
            new Brand{
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Unknown"
            },
            new Brand{
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Clorox"
            },
            new Brand{
                Id = 3,
                Name = "Glad"
            }
        };
        var brandData = brandList.AsQueryable();

        productList = new List<Product>{
            new Product{
                Id = "0000000001",
                ParentAsin = "0000000010",
                Title = "Mocked Product #1",
                ReleaseDate = DateTime.Now,
                BrandId = 1,
                CategoryId = 1,
                SegmentId = 1,
                TypeId = 1,
                Brand = brandList.ElementAt(0)
            }, 
            new Product{
                Id = "0000000002",
                ParentAsin = "0000000010",
                Title = "Mocked Product #2",
                ReleaseDate = DateTime.Now,
                BrandId = 1,
                CategoryId = 1,
                SegmentId = 1,
                TypeId = 1,
                Brand = brandList.ElementAt(0)
            },
            new Product{
                Id = "0000000003",
                ParentAsin = "0000000010",
                Title = "Mocked Product #3",
                ReleaseDate = DateTime.Now,
                BrandId = 2,
                CategoryId = 3,
                SegmentId = 3,
                TypeId = 2,
                Brand = brandList.ElementAt(1)
            }
        };
        var productData = productList.AsQueryable();

        brandList.ElementAt(1).Products.Add(productList.ElementAt<Product>(2));

        var mockProductSet = new Mock<DbSet<Product>>();
        mockProductSet.As<IQueryable<Product>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(productData.Provider);
        mockProductSet.As<IQueryable<Product>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(productData.Expression);
        mockProductSet.As<IQueryable<Product>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(productData.ElementType);
        mockProductSet.As<IQueryable<Product>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(productData.GetEnumerator());

        var mockBrandSet = new Mock<DbSet<Brand>>();
        mockBrandSet.As<IQueryable<Brand>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(brandData.Provider);
        mockBrandSet.As<IQueryable<Brand>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(brandData.Expression);
        mockBrandSet.As<IQueryable<Brand>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(brandData.ElementType);
        mockBrandSet.As<IQueryable<Brand>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(brandData.GetEnumerator());

        var mockContext = new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>() { CallBase = true };
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.Set<Product>()).Returns(mockProductSet.Object);
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.Set<Brand>()).Returns(mockBrandSet.Object);

        unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(mockContext.Object);
        brandRepo = new BrandRepository(mockContext.Object);
        productRepo = new ProductRepository(mockContext.Object);
        controller = new ProductController(productRepo, unitOfWork, brandRepo, categoryRepo, segmentRepo, typeRepo);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestReturnEditedModel()
    {
        Product product = productList.ElementAt<Product>(1);
        product.BrandId = 3;
        product.CategoryId = 2;
        product.SegmentId = 2;
        product.TypeId = 3;

        controller.Edit(product, "Return value");

        Product result = productRepo.Get(product.Id);
        Assert.AreEqual(product.Id, result.Id);
        Assert.AreEqual(3, result.BrandId);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, result.CategoryId);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, result.SegmentId);
        Assert.AreEqual(3, result.TypeId);
    }
}
```

I provided only the test that is failing.

Here is the controller function being called

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,ParentAsin,ReleaseDate,BrandId,CategoryId,SegmentId,TypeId")]Product model, string returnAction)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> selectedIds = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        selectedIds.Add("BrandId", model.BrandId);
        selectedIds.Add("CategoryId", model.CategoryId);
        selectedIds.Add("SegmentId", model.SegmentId);
        selectedIds.Add("TypeId", model.TypeId);
        PopulateAllDropDownLists(selectedIds);
        return View(model);
    }

    model.Brand = _brandRepo.Get(model.BrandId);
    model.Category = _categoryRepo.Get(model.CategoryId);
    model.Segment = _segmentRepo.Get(model.SegmentId);
    model.Type = _typeRepo.Get(model.TypeId);
    _repository.Update(model);
    _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction(returnAction);
}
```

`_brandRepo` is of type `IBrandRepository` and after all the implementations and inheritance, the function `Get()` is in a Generic repository class.

Here is the Get function that is being called.

```
public virtual TEntity Get(TId id)
{
    return this.DbSet.Single(x => (object)x.Id == (object)id);
}
```

The return line is the what is throwing the error.

Since this is a test and I'm mocking the data, I know that the Id being passed in is correct. It starts off as an `int` and the `Id` of `Brand` is an `int` as well, but to make this generic, the property is of type `TId` is a generic type of the interface `TEntity` which all models implement.

Here is TEntity

```
public interface IEntity<TId>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the unique identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The unique identifier.</value>
    TId Id { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is a mocking issue or an issue with using generic types. Can someone help with this.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this with a smaller unit test? There is a lot going on in your example.

Comment: @RyanGates I took out of the code of the test setup and I am still able to recreate the error. It has to do when I query the mocked `DbSet<Brand>`

Answer (score 3):

That looks way too complicated; you could just use a generic method to create a mock for any DbSet...

```
public static class DbSetMock
{
    public static Mock<DbSet<T>> CreateFrom<T>(List<T> list) where T : class
    {
        var internalQueryable = list.AsQueryable();
        var mock = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
        mock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.Provider).Returns(internalQueryable.Provider);
        mock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.Expression).Returns(internalQueryable.Expression);
        mock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.ElementType).Returns(internalQueryable.ElementType);
        mock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(()=> internalQueryable.GetEnumerator());
        mock.As<IDbSet<T>>().Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>(element => list.Add(element));
        mock.As<IDbSet<T>>().Setup(x => x.Remove(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>(element => list.Remove(element));
        return mock;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
 var mockBrandSet = DbSetMock.CreateFrom(brandList);
```

Since the data inside of the list and the DbSet are the same you can check the list to assert your manipulations.

Comment: For EFCore, don't forget to remove .As<IDbSet<T>>(), because there's no such Interface and .As<DbSet<T>>() will fail. The setup for Add and Remove will work as expected.

Comment: For EFCore it might be even simpler to derive a new TestDatabaseContext from your context and set it up as in memory database.

public TestDatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<YourDbContext> options)   : base(options) { }

public static DbContextOptions<YourDbContext> GetDBOptions()
{
  return new DbContextOptionsBuilder<YourDbContext>()
    .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
    .Options;
}

Comment: as some people pointed out in a similar post, setting up InMemoryDb replaces one dependency with another and makes it more of an Intergration test.

Comment: That of course is true. But in the end you want to write tests that cover your business logic and you want a setup that is incredible fast and easy to use. So at this point I would recommend the InMemory approach over the DbSetMock since it is similar fast and does not have the extension method problems with .Include .ThenInclude etc.

Answer (score 0):

If at any point you try to access the DbSets via their properties and not via `Set<>` is what would cause that problem if they were not setup. Although call base was true in the original example, the `DbContext` would internally try to discover `DbSets` and initializes them which would fail when mocking the DbContext. This is what they would have to setup in the mock to override the default behavior.

```
var mockContext = new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>();
mockContext.Setup(m => m.Set<Product>()).Returns(mockProductSet.Object);
mockContext.Setup(m => m.Set<Brand>()).Returns(mockBrandSet.Object);
mockContext.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(mockProductSet.Object);
mockContext.Setup(m => m.Brands).Returns(mockBrandSet.Object);
```

Also when setting up the `GetEnumerator()`, use a function to allow for multiple call

eg

```
mockProductSet.As<IQueryable<Product>>()
    .Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator())
    .Returns(() => productData.GetEnumerator());
```