# mocked DbSet does return value when using genrics

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, generics, moq

This is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981054/mocked-dbset-not-returning-an-object)

I am mocking a DbContext with multiple DbSets. I add objects to the mocked objects but when I try to query a specific object by its `id`, it throws an error.

```
AmazonReport.Tests.ProductTests.ProductControllerTest.TestReturnEditedModel:
    System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains no matching element
```

I have narrowed down the issue to this function(the `foreach` loop is there to verify that the id im passing in is in the DbSet, which it is)

```
public virtual TEntity Get(TId id)
    {
        foreach(TEntity b in this.DbSet)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b.Id + " and  " + id);
        }
        return this.DbSet.Single(x => (object)x.Id == (object)id);
        //return this.DbSet.Single(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Id) == Convert.ToInt32(id));
        //return this.DbSet.SingleOrDefault(x => (object)x.Id == (object)id);
    }
```

As is, it does not work. However, if I comment out the current return statement and use `return this.DbSet.Single(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Id) == Convert.ToInt32(id));` it will not throw the error.

So my question is, why does the compare not return any objects when the `DbSet` contains an object with `id == 3` and the passed in `TId id == 3`?

Comment: Can we see the set up code for the mocked DbSet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because by casting both up to `object`, reference equality is now used instead of value equality. Here's a really boiled down example of what's happening:

```
int i = 1;
int j = 1;

bool eq = ((object)i) == ((object)j); // false
```

Whereas directly comparing two integers with `==` compares the two by value.

Comment: Thanks. Would the `object.equals()` function work to compare the two?

Comment: Yes, `object.Equals` will compare the arguments by value if they are value types. I'm not sure that that will play nicely with EF though.

Comment: I didn't actually see that comparison. Although OP is Moq-ing DbSet, it may be possible he has not Moq-ed the GetEnumerator method which would cause Linq extension methods like `Single` to fail (assuming he hasn't done a partial mock)

Comment: @DanPantry: The exception indicate that `Single` did not return a value--meaning that `GetEnumerator` is probably returning *something* (even if it's an empty collection).

Comment: @DanPantry I did set up the `GetEnumerator` method, `mockBrandSet.As<IQueryable<Brand>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(brandData.GetEnumerator());`. I can post the code where I setup mocked `DbContext` and `DbSet`s, but it is about 150 lines long.