# How do I test that an item was added to a mocked DbContext?

Tags: entity-framework, nunit, moq

I have a question that is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072860/how-do-you-mock-adding-items-to-a-repository-or-dbcontext-using-moq).

However none of the answers are going to be acceptable in my situation.  I have implemented several of the classes that Microsoft suggests [here](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#test/EntityFramework/FunctionalTests/TestDoubles/MockableDbSetTests.cs) and have been struggling with a scenario that I feel is quite common.

I need to test that an item that is being created in a controller's action is correctly being saved to the database.  Here's the controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("CreateUser")]
public virtual async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateUser(RegisterViewModel viewModel)
{
    ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser(false, true, true, viewModel.UserName,
        viewModel.FirstName, viewModel.LastName, viewModel.EmailAddress);

    try
    {
        user.Salt = HashUtilities.GetSalt();
        user.Password = HashUtilities.GetHashedValue(viewModel.Password, user.Salt);

        // This is what I want to assert happened
        _dbContext.ApplicationUsers.Add(user);

        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok(user);                
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        List<string> messages = new List<string>();
        foreach (DbEntityValidationResult eve in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
            foreach (DbValidationError dve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                messages.Add(dve.ErrorMessage);

        string message = string.Join("\n\n", messages);

        return BadRequest(message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return InternalServerError(ex);
    }
}
```

And here is my test.  Some of the class/method implementations such as `InMemoryAsyncQueryable` are directly copied from MS's suggestion on the codeplex link.

```
// Arrange            
var viewModel = new RegisterViewModel
{
    ConfirmPassword = "abc123",
    EmailAddress = "Test@test.com",
    FirstName = "Test",
    LastName = "User1",
    Password = "abc123",
    UserName = "TestUser1" 
};
var queryableUsers = new List<ApplicationUser>().AsQueryable();
var users = DataUtilities.CreateMockQueryableSet<ApplicationUser>(new InMemoryAsyncQueryable<ApplicationUser>(queryableUsers));                     

var mockContext = new Mock<MainContext>();
mockContext.Setup(x => x.ApplicationUsers).Returns(users.Object);

var controller = new ApplicationUserController(mockContext.Object);

// Act
var result = controller.CreateUser(viewModel).Result;

// Assert            
Assert.IsInstanceOf<OkNegotiatedContentResult<ApplicationUser>>(result);           
mockContext.Verify(x => x.SaveChangesAsync());

// Test for persistence to the DbSet this is what is breaking down.  
// My ApplicationUsers.Count() is 0 when I'm expecting 1.
Assert.AreEqual(mockContext.Object.ApplicationUsers.Count(), 1);
var testUser = mockContext.Object.ApplicationUsers.First();
```

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I've found that testing this kind of behavior is really difficult. I'd advise you to take a look at a solution for DbContext wrapping in memory, such as [the Effort library](http://effort.codeplex.com/).

I explained how I use it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25978157/3204): it was for Entity Framework but I think the same behavior can be used in your case.

Comment: THank you for your answer, but I ended up using a class from the codeplex link that I had previously overlooked, the InMemoryDbSet<T> worked for what I needed:  http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#test/EntityFramework/FunctionalTests/TestDoubles/InMemoryDbSet.cs